# Wait ending coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

I need to make a request and wait for it to complete in order to assign its value to a variable.
Like this

`nameClient = Repository(applicationContext).getClient().toString()`

1. In this variant, "unknown" is immediately returned, and only after that the coroutine is performed.

```
  fun getClient(): String? {
     var nameClient: String? = "unknown"
     callsApiScope.launch {

        val deferred = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            callsApi.getClient(GetClientDTO(phonenumberString))
        }

        val response = deferred.await()
        val body = response.body()
        ...
        nameClient = nameObject.getString("fullName")
    }


     return nameClient?: nameClient
    }
```

2. In this variant, the process reaches job.join() and that's where everything ends

```
fun getClient(): String? {
         var nameClient: String? = null
         runBlocking {
             val job = callsApiScope.launch {

             val deferred = async(Dispatchers.Main) {
                 callsApi.getClient(GetClientDTO("+phonenumberString"))
             }

             val response = deferred.await()
             val body = response.body()
             ...
             nameClient = nameObject.getString("fullName")

             }
         }
             job.join()
         }
     return nameClient
    }
```

How can I wait and return the value ?

Comment: Simply: `runBlocking { callsApi.getClient(...) }`. But if this function is called from the main thread, then you can't really wait without blocking the thread. You need to redesign your code.

Comment: Please fix your indentation and also note that you have an extra non-matching closing `}` in your second example. It's hard to read your code as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to decide when your function should return. You generally have two options:

1. Return when the async call's result is prepared. (e.g. if the api takes 10 seconds to return a response, the function will return after 10 seconds. The caller will be blocked for 10 seconds.)
2. Return before the result is prepared. (e.g. even if the api takes 10 seconds to return a response, return immediately.)

The option 1 can return the response we need, as we gave it enough time. However, in the option 2, it is impossible for it to return the response we need, as we did not give it enough time. So for option 2, the function must return some kind of "future" result. It's not there yet, but will be in future.

If you are familiar with the concept of `Promise` in JS or `java.util.concurrent.Future`, that is what the option 2 should return.

What you are confused here is that in your first variant, you want your code to return immediately, but you want the exact result. That is not possible. You either have to give it enough time or get "future" result. (In coroutines, the "future" result is called `Deferred`.)

In your first variant, you launched a job, and returned the value, without giving the time for the job to end. Hence always the default value was returned.

In your second variant, you did give the function enough time, via calling your suspending functions in the `runBlocking` block. This is a correct approach and should generally work, but I suppose what is wrong here is below: (I might be wrong)

```kotlin
val deferred = async(Dispatchers.Main) {
    callsApi.getClient(GetClientDTO("+phonenumberString"))
}
```

If you are calling this code from `Dispatchers.Main`, this job will be scheduled after current code runs. However, since you are already in `Dispatchers.Main`, and you are blocking your thread with `deferred.await()`, you are effectively creating a deadlock.

Your `callsApi` can run after `deferred.await` is done, but `deferred.await` will only be finished when `callsApi` runs. It's a deadlock.

Instead, since you have already called `runBlocking`, just call `val response = callsApi.getClient(GetClientDTO("+phonenumberString"))`. This will block the current coroutine scope until the result is fetched and will provide the result you need without creating the deadlock.

But please remember that you indeed have two options, as I wrote at the start of this answer. 1. Blocking, 2. non-blocking. Generally, If you are calling from main thread, or non-blockable thread, you should avoid blocking calls.

What I usually do is that, from the main thread, I launch a long-running job on the background, and when the job is finished, I switch back to the main thread. (if it's not needed, I don't switch back to the main thread.)

So below is how things generally go. (for activities, use `lifecycleScope` instead of `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope`)

```kotlin
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        longRunningJob()
        // do non-UI job with the result
    }

    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        // do UI job with the result
    }
}
```

(please note that it is generally recommended to [inject dispatchers](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices))

You should probably read a few more articles on how coroutines work and the best practice of using coroutines in Android. Start with below resources:

1. Learn the basics.
   https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html
2. Have a hands-on practice.
   https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-coroutines#0
3. As you get familiar with coroutines, learn in-depth knowledge of coroutines.
   https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-guide.html
4. As you get familiar with coroutines in Android, learn the best practices.
   https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices

If you are stuck, reach out to people in the official slack too. https://slack-chats.kotlinlang.org/ for other Kotlin communities, see https://kotlinlang.org/community/

May your journey with Coroutines and Android be happy, enjoyable, and less stressful.